# date difference in years between two date picker content controls word 2016 vba code

Tags: vba, datepicker, ms-word, date-difference, word-contentcontrol

I've got two date picker content controls titled dateofbirth and another titled datefirstseen. i tried determining the difference in years to be computed into a text box content control on the-same first page of the form titled ageasatlastbirthday

i tried this code

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim CCtrl As ContentControl, DtStart As Long, DtEnd As Long
With ContentControl
  If .Title = "DateofBirth" Then
    If IsDate(.Range.Text) Then
      DtStart = CDate(.Range.Text)
      With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("DateRecruitedDateFirstSeen ")(1)
        If IsDate(.Range.Text) Then DtEnd = CDate(.Range.Text)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Ageatlastbirthday ")(1).Range.Text = Int((DtEnd - DtStart) / 365)
      End With
    End If
  End If
  If .Title = "DateRecruitedDateFirstSeen" Then
    If IsDate(.Range.Text) Then
      DtEnd = CDate(.Range.Text)
      With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("DateofBirth")(1)
        If IsDate(.Range.Text) Then DtStart = CDate(.Range.Text)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Ageatlastbirthday ")(1).Range.Text = Int((DtEnd - DtStart) / 365)
      End With
    End If
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

I imputed this code into the 'thisdocument' section as a document with ContentControlOnExit format but it still doesn't work.

Please help modify into a workable code.

Comment: Add this code in the active sheet, rather than document. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you don't need "Dim CCtrl As ContentControl".
Both ContentControls passed in to the Sub *better* be date Content Controls. If the .Range.Text is not a date, your routine will do nothing. You better issue a  dire warning if the .Range.Text is not a date. Yep, you better put in some diagnostic messages to see what's going wrong, such as

```
Debug.Print .Range.Text
```